# How to store JS selection data after page refresh

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, razor, pagination, filtering

I am trying to create an ecommerce page. I want to make category selections with using checkboxes. It can make the filtering and give me the necessary data; the backend works. But when I change the page (pagination feature), the category selection is getting lost. So the data is not being stable anymore. The list gives me the default SQL query again. How can I make it stable? How do I store my selection?

**EDIT (problem occures to this if I use localStorage, based on the answer)**
If I need to give an example to make sure you understand better. You have 10 item in your data, you display 6 for each, when you change to page two you need to see the rest of 4 data. My problem occures here, I don't see the rest 4 data. I see the first 6 again in everypage. I see the rest 4 data(for a sec) , then I see the first 6 data immidiatly.

*If more code blocks are needed I can edit the post*

**Controller**

```
[Authorize]
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(GetECommerceIndexQuery request, List<int> categoryIds)
{
    var result = await MediatrSend(request);
    return View(result);
}

[Authorize]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetCategories([FromBody] List<int> selectedIds)
{
    var result = await MediatrSend(new GetECommerceIndexQuery { CategoryIds = selectedIds});
    return Json(result);
}
```

**Query File**

```
 public class GetECommerceIndexQuery : MediatR.IRequest<ECommerceListDTO>
    {
        public ClaimModel ClaimModel { get; set; }
        public List<int> CategoryIds { get; set; }
        public int Page { get; set; } = 1;
        public int PageSize { get; set; } = 6;
    }

    public class GetECommerceIndexQueryHandler : IRequestHandler<GetECommerceIndexQuery, ECommerceListDTO>
    {
        private readonly IECommerceProductRepository _eCommerceProductRepository;

        public GetECommerceIndexQueryHandler(IECommerceProductRepository eCommerceProductRepository)
        {
            _eCommerceProductRepository = eCommerceProductRepository;
        }
        public async Task<ECommerceListDTO> Handle(GetECommerceIndexQuery request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            ECommerceListDTO response = new ECommerceListDTO();

            int page = request.Page;
            int pageSize = request.PageSize;

            var products = await _eCommerceProductRepository.GetECommerceProductList(request.CategoryIds);

            var totalProducts = products.Count();
            var totalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)totalProducts / pageSize);
            var paginatedProducts = products.Skip((page - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize);

            response.MetaData = new DatatableMetaDTO
            {
                page = page,
                pages = totalPages,
                perpage = pageSize,
                total = totalProducts,
            };

            response.ProductData = paginatedProducts;
            response.CategoryData = await _eCommerceProductRepository.GetECommerceCategoryList();

            return response;
        }
    }
```

**Pagination**

```
 <!-- Pagination Buttons -->
                            <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                                <ul class="pagination">
                                    @for (int i = 1; i <= Model.MetaData.pages; i++)
                                    {
                                        <li class="page-item @(i == Model.MetaData.page ? "active" : "")">
                                            <a class="page-link" href="@Url.Action("Index", new { page = i })">@i</a>
                                        </li>
                                    }
                                </ul>
                            </div>
```

**Script**

```
@section scripts {
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".checkbox-item").click(function () {
                var selectedValues = $(".checkbox-item:checked").map(function () {
                    return parseInt(this.value, 10);
                }).get();

                var jsonData = JSON.stringify(selectedValues);

                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("GetCategories", "ECommerce")',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: jsonData,
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    success: function (data) {
                        console.log(data);
                        renderProducts(data.ProductData);
                    },
                    error: function (error) {
                        console.error('Error Occurred:', error);
                    }
                });
            });

            function renderProducts(products) {
                $('#productContainer').empty();

                $.each(products, function (index, product) {
                    var productUrl = '@Url.Action("ProductDetail", new { id = 0 })'.replace("0", product.Id);

                    var productHtml = `
                                <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-12 col-xxl-4">
                                    <a href="${productUrl}" class="product-link">
                                        <div class="card card-custom gutter-b card-stretch">
                                            <div class="card-body d-flex flex-column rounded bg-light justify-content-between">
                                                <div class="text-center rounded mb-7">
                                                    <img src="assets/media/products/${product.ProductName}" class="mw-100 w-200px" alt="${product.ProductName}">
                                                </div>
                                                <div>
                                                    <h4 class="font-size-h5">
                                                        <span class="text-dark-75 font-weight-bolder">${product.ProductName}</span>
                                                    </h4>
                                                    <div class="font-size-h6 text-muted font-weight-bolder">${product.Price}</div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </a>
                                </div>`;

                    $('#productContainer').append(productHtml);
                });
            }
        });
    </script>
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve your issue  losing category selections when changing pages and seeing the same data on every page you can follow this below updated code:

```
@section scripts {
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var selectedCategories = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('selectedCategories')) || [];
            var currentPage = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('currentPage')) || 1;
            
            $(".checkbox-item").each(function() {
                var value = parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
                if (selectedCategories.includes(value)) {
                    $(this).prop('checked', true);
                }
            });

            loadProducts();

            $(".checkbox-item").click(function () {
                updateSelectedCategories();
                currentPage = 1; 
                localStorage.setItem('currentPage', currentPage);
                loadProducts();
            });

            $(".page-link").click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                currentPage = parseInt($(this).text(), 10);
                localStorage.setItem('currentPage', currentPage);
                loadProducts();
            });

            function updateSelectedCategories() {
                selectedCategories = $(".checkbox-item:checked").map(function () {
                    return parseInt(this.value, 10);
                }).get();
                localStorage.setItem('selectedCategories', JSON.stringify(selectedCategories));
            }

            function loadProducts() {
                var jsonData = JSON.stringify(selectedCategories);

                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("GetCategories", "ECommerce")',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: jsonData,
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    success: function (data) {
                        console.log(data);
                        renderProducts(data.ProductData);
                        updatePagination(data.MetaData.page, data.MetaData.pages);
                    },
                    error: function (error) {
                        console.error('Error Occurred:', error);
                    }
                });
            }

            function renderProducts(products) {
                $('#productContainer').empty();
                // ... (same as before)
            }

            function updatePagination(currentPage, totalPages) {
                $('.pagination').empty();
                for (var i = 1; i <= totalPages; i++) {
                    var isActive = i === currentPage ? "active" : "";
                    var pageItem = `<li class="page-item ${isActive}">
                                        <a class="page-link" href="#">${i}</a>
                                    </li>`;
                    $('.pagination').append(pageItem);
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
}
```

Comment: It is kind of working, but not fully. If I move to another page with pagination, it does not put the data for that page. The initial data is constantly displayed on other pages. Always the first six data are displayed for each page. I can't see the rest of the data. Before the local storage, it was working without problems. It pops up the rest of the data without the filtering than displays the filtered first six data again. I couldn't fix the problem

Comment: Did you have time to check the problem Jalpa, I updated the post by the problem that I  mentioned?

Comment: @OnurSerbes i have updated my post code based on your description with pagination issue. let me know if it still does not work

Comment: Thanks Jalpa, I updated the code with more modifications based on your answer. Now it's working and I shared the full answer to the post.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the Jalpa Panchal's answer I modified the script a bit more and I made the code working without problem. I fixed the pagination and catgeory problem. Here is the updated and finalized version of the code

**Controller**

```
    [Authorize]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetCategories([FromBody] GetECommerceIndexQuery request)
    {
        var result = await MediatrSend(request);
        return Json(result);
    }
```

**Script**

```
@section scripts {
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var selectedCategories = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('selectedCategories')) || [];
            var currentPage = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('currentPage')) || 1;

            // Function to update selected categories
            function updateSelectedCategories() {
                selectedCategories = $(".checkbox-item:checked").map(function () {
                    return parseInt(this.value, 10);
                }).get();
                localStorage.setItem('selectedCategories', JSON.stringify(selectedCategories));
            }

            // Function to load products and update pagination
            function loadProducts() {
                var jsonData = JSON.stringify({
                    CategoryIds: selectedCategories,
                    Page: currentPage
                });

                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("GetCategories", "ECommerce")',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: jsonData,
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    success: function (data) {
                        console.log(data);
                        renderProducts(data.ProductData);
                        updatePagination(currentPage, data.MetaData.pages);
                    },
                    error: function (error) {
                        console.error('Error Occurred:', error);
                    }
                });
            }

            // Function to render products
            function renderProducts(products) {
                $('#productContainer').empty();

                $.each(products, function (index, product) {
                    var productUrl = '@Url.Action("ProductDetail", new { id = 0 })'.replace("0", product.Id);

                    var productHtml = `
                                                <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-12 col-xxl-4">
                                                    <a href="${productUrl}" class="product-link">
                                                        <div class="card card-custom gutter-b card-stretch">
                                                            <div class="card-body d-flex flex-column rounded bg-light justify-content-between">
                                                                <div class="text-center rounded mb-7">
                                                                    <img src="assets/media/products/${product.ProductName}" class="mw-100 w-200px" alt="${product.ProductName}">
                                                                </div>
                                                                <div>
                                                                    <h4 class="font-size-h5">
                                                                        <span class="text-dark-75 font-weight-bolder">${product.ProductName}</span>
                                                                    </h4>
                                                                    <div class="font-size-h6 text-muted font-weight-bolder">${product.Price}</div>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </a>
                                                </div>`;

                    $('#productContainer').append(productHtml);
                });
            }

            // Function to update pagination
            function updatePagination(currentPage, totalPages) {
                $('.pagination').empty();
                for (var i = 1; i <= totalPages; i++) {
                    var isActive = i === currentPage ? "active" : "";
                    var pageItem = `<li class="page-item ${isActive}">
                                                <a class="page-link" href="#" data-page="${i}">${i}</a>
                                            </li>`;
                    $('.pagination').append(pageItem);
                }
            }

            // Initial load of products and pagination
            loadProducts(currentPage);

            // Click event for category checkboxes
            $(".checkbox-item").click(function () {
                updateSelectedCategories();
                currentPage = 1;
                localStorage.setItem('currentPage', currentPage);
                loadProducts();
            });

            // Click event for pagination buttons
            $(".pagination").on("click", ".page-link", function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var page = parseInt($(this).data("page"));
                currentPage = page;
                localStorage.setItem('currentPage', currentPage);
                loadProducts();
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```